# Characterizing dense sets in finite topological space such that no proper subset is dense

Tags: general-topology

Assume we have a topological space $X$, with its topology characterized by a certain closure operator, $\overline{()}\colon\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$, that we know explicitly.

I don't know if there exists some name for this concept, but let's say a subset $A\subset X$ is minimally dense if it is dense and it doesn't contain any proper dense subset.

Is there an easy way to characterize if a certain dense set $A$ is minimally dense? For the problem I'm trying to tackle, it is possible to assume $X$ to be finite, but it is desirable to compute the minimum number of closures possible, so computing the closure of every subset of $A$ is out of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $A$ is not minimally dense, then there is some $a\in A$ such that $A\setminus\{a\}$ is still dense.  So you don't need to compute the closures of all subsets, just the ones obtained by removing a singleton.  Moreover, $A\setminus\{a\}$ is dense iff its closure contains $a$, since then its closure will contain $A$ and thus have to be all of $X$.  So, $A$ is minimally dense iff every point of $A$ is isolated in $A$, i.e. $A$ has the discrete topology.

When $A$ is finite, it is discrete iff every singleton is closed, so you can test this by just computing the closure of $\{a\}$ for each $a\in A$ and seeing whether it contains any other points of $A$.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks! Also, in my concrete problem it simplifies everything a lot, maybe it was just the intended way